# Sinon stub withArgs ignores extra arguments

Tags: testing, sinon

My production code looks like:

```
exports.convertWord = number => { /* some logic here */ }
exports.methodUnderTest = () => {
    return exports.convertWord(1);
}
```

Test code:

```
const mockConvertToWord = sinon.stub();
mockConvertToWord.withArgs(1).returns('one');
fileUnderTest.convertWord = mockConvertToWord;

const result = fileUnderTest.methodUnderTest();

expect(result).toBeEqual('one');
```

Test above is green. I expect my test will break if I change prod code to this:

```
exports.convertWord = number => { /* some logic here */ }
exports.methodUnderTest = () => {
    return exports.convertWord(1, 'another arg');
}
```

but it's not. Sinon works fine even when I pass extra params which I didn't point in `withArgs` method. How can I tell sinon to return value only when method has been called with exact number of params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### stub

One way to do this is to use [`stub.callsFake(fakeFunction)`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.3.5/stubs/#stubcallsfakefakefunction):

```js
mockConvertToWord.callsFake((...args) => args.length === 1 && args[0] === 1 ? 'one' : undefined);
```

An alternative approach with a `stub` is to use a `sinon.assert` to make sure the `stub` was called with the epected arguments as noted by @deerawan.

---

### mock

Another approach is to use a `mock`:

```js
const mock = sinon.mock(fileUnderTest);
mock.expects('convertWord').withExactArgs(1).returns("one");

const result = fileUnderTest.methodUnderTest();  

expect(result).toBeEqual('one');
mock.verify();
```

Comment: Is there more readable alternative? I agree it works, but it's going to be a hell if you use such construction in each mock.

Comment: @IlyaEremin I added an example using a `mock` instead of a `stub` which provides `withExactArgs` and gives a nicely readable result.  I'm surprised that `stub` doesn't provide `withExactArgs`, looks like it has been [discussed but never implemented](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/461).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, perhaps you can try to check the call of `convertToWord` like

```
...
expect(result).toBeEqual('one');

// check the function 
sinon.assert.alwaysCalledWithExactly(mockConvertToWord, '1');
```

Ref:

- https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.3.4/assertions/#sinonassertalwayscalledwithexactlyspy-arg1-arg2-

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is suitable. Personally I don't like `sinon.assert` syntax. And also if I use such syntax then I have to write twice same logic in arrange and in assert.